# shopify: how to redirect user after login form submit on shopify

Tags: shopify

I am trying to direct users to a specific page after they submit the registration form.

I looked around, and some people suggest using something like this:

```
{% form 'create_customer' %}
  <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/pages/registration-success"/>
```

However, that does not work.

Does any one know how to specify what page a user lands on after submitting a form in Shopify?    (I have checked the documentation,  and spoken with Shopify tech support. there isn't any documentation on this topic)

Answer (score 1):

I found this somewhere on the web and seems to work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkout_url" value="/pages/registration-success">
```

I'm just using it in a `{%form 'customer_login' %}` though and setting it via script to location.href. This allows me to have customers return to the same page after logging in.